# Insert data with missing columns into existing table using BULK INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I've created a table with 6 columns, but the data file has only 3 columns. How do I insert using BULK INSERT?

```
CREATE TABLE Persons(
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(50),
    FirstName varchar(50),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(50)
    email varchar(50)
);
```

I have only these 3 columns

```
FirstName,LastName,City
```

This is the code I've tried

```
BULK INSERT Persons
FROM 'C:\Persons.csv'
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR =',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
```

Comment: Use an intermediate staging table in TempDB.

Comment: Another option is to use `OPENROWSET(BULK, ...)`, which allows you to incorporate the missing columns in a `SELECT`.